# ADT requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-2.2-froyo

I'm installing the Android SDK on a fresh installation of Fedora 14 (Linux). I installed eclipse, and ran the tools/android sdk tool to install all the Eclipse components for the SDK. I was able to get DDMS to install when selecting it by itself.

And for the last component - the Android developer tools, I'm getting the ugly error message pasted below.

Now I'm Stuck in Eclipse dependency hell.

I've searched through the available packages in Fedora and I can't find the one that has the files necessary to satisfy this Eclipse dependency. Can anybody please translate what it is that Eclipse is asking for and what Fedora package it lives in?

The ugly error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 269, accepted):

I've just encountered exactly the same problem in Eclipse 3.6 (Helios). After plenty of Googling I came across this link:

http://code.google.com/intl/es/eclipse/docs/faq.html#wstinstallerror

> During installation, there's an error
>   about requiring
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui. How do I fix
>   that?
>
> The Google Plugin for Eclipse depends
>   on other specific Eclipse components,
>   such as WST. Your installation of
>   Eclipse may not yet include all of
>   them, but they can be easily installed
>   by following these instructions.
>   Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)
>
> 1. Select Help > Install New Software...
> 2. Click the link for Available Software Sites.
> 3. Ensure there is an update site named Helios. If this is not present,
>      click Add... and enter
>      http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios
>      for the Location.
> 4. Now go through the installation steps; Eclipse should download and
>      install the plugin's dependencies.

(There are examples in that page for 3.5 (Galileo), 3.4 (Ganymede) & 3.3 (Europa) for anyone with different versions)

The exact same steps work for 3.7 (Indigo) as well.

Just use `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo` for the location.

Juno: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno`

Kepler: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler`

*Note: Step four is not necessary. Only steps one to three are necessary.*

Comment: and make sure you have that check-box that says 'include update sites' checked.

Comment: This did not work for me because that link was already enabled. Instead I had to remove ~/.eclipse, and then add that link. However it *still* didn't work because it complains about conflicting packages (Ubuntu 11.10). In the end the only solution is to completely apt-get remove eclipse, and download it from the eclipse website. Then everything works properly.

Comment: @ugs answer did it for me on windows, the problem was that I normally removed it for updates but it is needed for a fresh instal.

Comment: @Warpzit Yup. I took quite some ( a lot of ) time to figure this silly mistake, so i thought it was worth mentioning here!

Comment: In the Juno site, there are 11 things that mention WDT. Which to get??

Comment: might be useful for smbd that JUNO url is  
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Comment: I just upticked cause everybody else did ... :)

Comment: For those wondering: once you add the link, you can just switch to the ADT link and you should be able to get the components to install without manually installing anything from the Eclipse link

Comment: Eclipse 3.8 is not listed separately but Indigo update site worked for me.Similarly for PDT it complained of missing components which works now :)

Comment: And what if you don't have Internet access so you can't get to that download.eclipse.org URL?

Answer (score 53):

For Eclipse 3.7 or Indigo the winning URL is

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

And for 3.8 it is

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Comment: I think 3.8 is still called Indigo, because it only contains bugfixes for 3.7. Codename for 4.2 is Juno.

Comment: i recently install eclipse 4.2 and uses the juno url and works fine

Comment: rubo77 is correct. 3.8+ is a maintenance version and it is still Indigo. It has only bugfixes. 4.2 is called Juno.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same problem in eclipse 3.7 indigo

and I have done the folowing:

1. help->install new software
2. click on "available software sites"
3. select all entries (CTRL-A) and remove them
4. add new entry at location http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
5. now add again the ADT location http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Just FYI for anybody reading this in the future, I had Indigo installed via the Ubuntu package, and this was exactly what I needed. I didn't need to delete ~/.eclipse, or uninstall the package, etc. So thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're downloaded and installed a Classic version of eclipse you are missing the essential Java Development Tools required by the Android SDK etc

I found that installing the Eclipse Java Development Tools & Java EE Tools solved this problem for me in Eclipse 3.7.

It seems obvious to many Java Developers but to those new to the IDE and JAVA etc it's important to note that they don't installed come with the "classic" version of Eclipse.

Adding the link to the Helios repo http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios wasn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

In windows 7

Run the eclipse as administrator

goto Windows->Preferences->Instal/update->check "all version of available softwares" and apply--> ok

goto Help->Install new software-> add-->put the URL add or ADT zip file -->ok

thats all and its working....

Answer (score 4):

I was also browsing these answers,but I couldn't get any answer to my problem.But through hit and trial I found the following solution.
First of all update your eclipse by going on Help-> Check for updates .Then, go to Install New Software and give adt location(local or url),then do check **Contact all update sited during install to find required software** and it would do the rest.

I am not sure whether this solution works well for other,but it worked for me and hope it works for some troubled developer out there

Answer (score 4):

And for the Juno-[version](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno):

You just have to add it - not to install anything.

Answer (score 3):

I found that removing `~/.eclipse` solved this issue for me on the stock Ubuntu eclipse

Answer (score 3):

For me, running win 7 64, eclipse 3.7.1 64, It was simply to run eclipse as admin, go through the listed steps.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ubuntu 11.10 I was able to fix that issue by reinstalling Eclipse (in my case 3.7) as follows:

```
    sudo apt-get purge eclipse
    sudo apt-get install eclipse.*
```

From there on installing the Android SDK just worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I got the above error because the Indigo and "Eclipse Project Updates" items in the "Available Software Sites" pane were disabled.
All I had to do was toggle them to the enabled state and my ADT Plugin installation went like a breeze (as far as eclipse installations go, I guess)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. 
Running **Windows 7 (64 bit), Eclipse *Indigo***. Tried all the different suggestions, but finally, simply ***unchecking*** *`Contact all update sites during install to find required software`* (running *Eclipse* as **Admin**, although I don't think this was important) got everything working fine. 
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Install Google Plugin for Eclipse corresponding to your version.
for 3.6 helios link is http://code.google.com/intl/es/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.6.html

for offline version http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html

hope it will solve mine problem as well as yours.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error in Windows Vista 32-bit when using **Eclipse Classic 3.7.2** package, but it worked well after I downloaded and used **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.

Answer (score 2):

straight steps to get your ADT plugin working

- Download eclipse helios EE IDE not the classic version
- After unzip directly go to Checks for Update from help menu
- After it get updated download ADT plugin offline version from ADROID site
- Now go to Help again -> Install New software -> add -> click on archive then point to your download ADT ADT-17.0.0.zip. Give any name in name field say ADT. click ok
- now from work with drop down select the adt plugin name which you given
- now go ahead with installation. enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

What I did (Helios):

1) Go to Help -> Install New Software...

2) Select or add new location http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios/

3) Check WTP of latest version checkbox and press next

4) Most probably u will get into *'additional dependecies required'* situation, **but that new screen will show u which packages have wst in their names, u should procede with installation of that *wst* packages**

5) U didn't get 4th point stuff. In that case u have required wst packages installed.

Enjoy. Or not... :)

Answer (score 1):

**Android developer**
For those using eclipse 3.7

add the following after the http:// prompt   download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Then click on "help" menu and click "check for updates

Answer (score 1):

To help remove some of the guess and check on which dependencies are needed.
After a fresh Ubuntu install I needed the following.

Error 1:

```
***Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846) requires ***'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Update site:
GEF and Draw2d Plugin from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

Error 2:

```
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Update site:
Eclipse XML Editors and Tool from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Answer (score 1):

Use
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ instead of https

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Fedora 16**

Note that this is now provided by a package, so the recommended Thing To Do is

```
  pkcon install eclipse-wtp-sourceediting
```

This appears to be a one-shot “magic bullet” to get everything that Android's ADK plug-in requires on Fedora 16 (at least).

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers worked for me. Having all the correct update sites in "available sites" was not enough to tell Eclipse how to find its dependencies.

Using Fedora 14 and Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1, I had to follow these steps to make the installation working:

1. Check and install "Linux Tools" from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
2. Check and install "Linux Tools" from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201109230900

After restarting Eclipse, I was able to finaly install the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

> During installation, there's an error about requiring
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui. How do I fix that?
>
> The Google Plugin for Eclipse depends on other specific Eclipse
>   components, such as WST. Your installation of Eclipse may not yet
>   include all of them, but they can be easily installed by following
>   these instructions. Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)
>
> Select Help > Install New Software... Click the link for Available
>   Software Sites. Ensure there is an update site named Helios. If this
>   is not present, click Add... and enter
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios for the Location. Now go
>   through the installation steps; Eclipse should download and install
>   the plugin's dependencies.

**//Try to install the extension "eclipse plugin development environment"**

Answer (score 1):

Use http instead of https:// and it will solve this problem.

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: An identical answer has been posted more than half a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Add [this](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno) for eclipse juno
I was able to install ADT plugin after this on ubuntu 12.04
.

Answer (score 1):

none of above worked for me. This did:

1. Remove Eclipse (I think this is discussed above).
2. Get THIS eclipse. (The others don't have java).
   [This eclipse has java in it, the apt-get one doesn't](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/R/eclipse-jee-juno-linux-gtk.tar.gz)
3. Follow these steps[This guy nailed it. It shouldn't be this hard, but it's not that bad...](http://colinrrobinson.com/technology/install-eclipse-ubuntu/)

After that, I was able to bring back my Android stuff via the normal "Install new Software",

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue to.  What i did was simply extract the eclipse package using `7-zip` instead of the inbuilt windows extractor.

Answer (score 1):

**Eclispe 4.2 Juno** Service Release 2

Trying to install **Google Plugin for Eclipse** failed even when "Contact all update sites" was enabled.
After installing the Juno **JST/WST Server** packages it worked.

Help > Install New Software...

Work with: Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Category: Web, XML, ...

- JST Server Adapters
- JST Server Adapters Extensions
- JST Server UI
- WST Server Adapters

Restart Eclipse

Help > Install New Software...

Work with: Google Plugin for Eclipse - https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

- Google App Engine Tools for Android
- Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2

Contact all update sites - **enabled**!

Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

[Google is your friend](http://code.google.com/intl/es/eclipse/docs/faq.html#wstinstallerror). Make sure you use the right version of Eclipse, and you *may* have to run Eclipse as root when installing.

The issue is that the versions of Eclipse that ship with Linux distributions are usually very generic in their configuration. It is unlikely that you will find the right package through your package manager, you want to use Eclipse's mechanism.

Comment: That instructions doesn't work for me with Eclipse 3.5 and ADT 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Downloading SDK tools and Installing the ADT bundle posed a problem for me on Windows and Linux.
After trying it in every way possible on both OS's even with my college lecturer with me for the Windows install, we couldn't get it working.

Both times the only way I got it working was by installing the Android ADT Bundle that includes Eclipse & SDK tools & ADT Plugin all in one.

apt-get remove eclipse-jdt and just download the bundle, it just works. :)

It's not from a repo but it works.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html