# Eclipse IDE,ADT for android SDk error

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I have ported from Windows 7 to ubunti linux 11.10 version.I installed Eclipse successfully,and when i go to add the ADT plugin,a configure error is desplaying.

The error says...

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

What may be the probable reason for this?And need suggestions for installing as soon as possible,Im getting late for my project...

Thnx in advance frndssssssssssss

Comment: Eclipse Platform  - Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the Android SDK for Windows is different from the Android SDK for Linux. If you are dual booted (like I am), you must have both, but installed in different locations. After you installed the Android SDK for Linux, you must repoint Eclipse to the new SDK. Once you do this, you can manually clean all of your projects (yes, they may all need to be cleaned) and begin work on your projects.

The location of the Linux SDK is [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r16-linux.tgz). Make sure you then follow the instructions located   on [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing).

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: I found the SDK for Linux,but the ADT is not connecting with the Eclipse...any other suggestions?

Comment: Now you have to download the ADT following the instructions on the page. Then point the ADT to the SDK. Goto menu Windows -> Preferences. On the left side, you will see Android. Click on that. At the top of that form, you can choose the SDK location.

Comment: The block code in my question is what is i receiving as an error when i try to connect the ADT....please check the question once more and answer....

Comment: I did check the question. You did not provide all of the information before, so I compensated by providing that information. Do not assume the answer is incorrect because I did not read. The answer was incorrect because until you verified the information above, that was the next logical troubleshooting step. Very little is more insulting than a questioner assuming an answerer incompetent due to a lack of info. I know this is frustrating for you, but please do not pass that frustration onto others trying to help.

Comment: How are you downloading the ADT? From the repository or manually?

Comment: This next page addresses messages similar to the one above, regarding Eclipse specific components that are missing. This would be your next step. Unfortunately, it doesn't have 3.7 specific information, but it works for 3.6 (my version) Here is the URL: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents

Comment: I didnt mean to frustrate you,but i passed my attitude that i felt...and i am downloading ADT via repository....Sorry if the way i commented was in such a way making u feel bad....thanks for the help frnd...

Comment: No problem. I'm not frustrated. I just wanted to make sure that you understood the tone that was coming across. Let me see if I can find a manual link for you (there used to be one).

Comment: You can manually download the ADT. The instructions for manual installation are at this page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html under Troubleshooting ADT Installation. Here is the link for the manual download: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-16.0.1.zip

Comment: Also, don't forget, Updating ADT may be required to fix and download the missing components.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error - you need to add the http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo update site to the available software sites.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found) for more details.

Comment: I've solved by removing/disable all other repos and add only the above + google adt Ref. http://i.imgur.com/vDyN5.png

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this today.  The simple fix for me was using the "http" version instead of "https" version of the URL given for the "Install New Software..." step of adding the ADT to Eclipse.

To clarify, I used:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

NOT

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

The install went smoothly after that.

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can find the latest ADT from here

**Mac**
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip﻿

**Windows 32 bit version** 
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

**Widnows 64 bit version**
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip﻿

**Linux 32 bit version**
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip

**Linux 64 bit version**
http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip﻿