# Installing Android Plugin Error with Eclipse Juno 4.2.0

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I downloaded [Eclipse-Juno Version: 4.2.0](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.2M4-201112092100/index.php).
But I am not able to install Android ADT on it. I am getting this error:

> requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

System Configurations: Win-7, 32-bit

I tried installing [ADT-15.0.1](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-15.0.1.zip) and [ADT-16.0.1](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-16.0.1.zip), but they are not working.

I know [the same issue is faced with versions lower version than 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found), but why also with 4.2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What package of Juno did you install? ADT requires part of the WST project, but I suspect that the Juno package you have doesn't include WST and probably doesn't include the update repository to automatically get it.

EDIT: Try using the **Eclipse for Java EE Developers** package as your starting point, as it includes WST features. Alternatively, you could try adding the Juno update site to your Eclipse and see if ADT gets it's required features. The Juno update site is `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/`

Comment: Juno - Classic Version as suggested by [Android Dev.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)  and i tried installing Offline which i always prefer.

Comment: Wrking with Eclipse for Java EE

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I installed Juno and that package I installed did not come with WST either.

I fixed this same problem by adding Juno update site at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/. You will find WST under "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development. For my own purpose I simply installed everything under this category and the problem went away.

Comment: Add in the update link http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/ is all you need todo, after this Eclipse will install the correct packages for you when installing ADT. You do not need to manually select packages.

Answer (score 5):

Glad I came across this question!  That said though, it appears I only needed to install the Eclipse XML Editors and Tools part of  Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development to resolve this.  Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

try this https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2

or use this -- > http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 <-- for instal android

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Install in eclipse:

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

It works well for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I solved by downloading [ADT-20.0.0.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip). I think different versions of eclipse support different versions of ADT.