# Having problems downloading Android Development Tools for Eclipse 4.1.0

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I tried to download the Development tools for the Android SDK last night and have been getting this error every time I try to download it ever since:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)

I've tried running Eclipse as an administrator, downloading the Google Plugin for Eclipse Galileo, and many assortment of things, but nothing seems to work.  Is there a Google plugin for 4.1.0, would I have to reinstall an earlier version of Eclipse, or am I missing something else entirely?

NB: I've been using Windows 7 64-bit Eclipse 4.1.0, as well as the 64-bit version of JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

1. android sdk dosen't support JDK 1.7, use 1.6.
2. you should use Eclipse 3.7. Eclipse 4.* is a work in progress and shouldn't be used in production environments yet.

Comment: I'll try your idea.  I'll return after about an hour or so after deleting my files and starting fresh.

Comment: I'm having trouble adding my new jre to the eclipse path: I've downloaded the JDK 1.6 and Eclipse 3.7, but eclipse cannot find my jre even though I've copied the jre6 folder to the eclipse root folder.

Comment: Forget it; I found the right jre folder in the jdk 1.6 folder.  Now, I'm having the similar problems I experience with 1.7: the Developer Tools aren't downloading.  I'll try running eclipse as administrator and see what happens.

Comment: Just downloaded, but I had to fly through some hoops to get it working: I had to download everything but the Android Development Tools the first go-around, then I was able to download the ADTs.  Now, all I need to do is figure out how the actual ADT work for the Android SDK in Eclipse. I think I properly set up the SDK I downloaded last night, but I don't see anything different in Eclipse, aside from the SDK and AVD buttons on the upper toolbar.

Comment: I was able to get everything working thanks to a YT tutorial (i.e. I found out how to set up an ADV, started a new project, and got the emulator working).  Thanks again to those who helped out.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention anything about the Android Development Tool (ADT) which is required to develop Android apps.
You can get it from here, http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
You will need Android SDK r16

Comment: I downloaded that, as well. I have the following tools downloaded from the SDK Manager: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, all items for Android 4.0.3 (API15).  Do I need more of these tools?

Answer (score 0):

Does my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8994687/639520) help?

Also note that there have been some documented bugs with running Eclipse in JDK 1.7 - make sure you have the very latest updates to JDK or use 1.6 instead.