# ADT Plugin Won't Install

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

I am using Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7 and have repeatedly tried to install the ADT Plugin for android but to no avail. I have tried: using Eclipse 3.6, downloading the .ZIP file, checking for updates and trying again, using the "http" protocol instead of the "https" in the repository. None of them worked.

However, whenever I try to install it, it either freezes at "calculating dependencies and requirements" or says

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)"

Someone please help, I desperately need android for my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What package of Eclipse did you download? Perhaps the package you have doesn't include some pre-requisite that ADT needs.See if my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988741/installing-android-plugin-error-with-eclipse-juno-4-2-0/) help solve your problem.

Also, it would help to see more of the failure reason. We know you're trying to install ADT, what's important is what comes after that, the part that tells which requires items can't be found.

Comment: I just tried adding the Juno update site, but it didn't work. the whole error message is posted above. If you read carefully, you see the only package which won't install is the development tools package (which is the most important one). I'll try EE Eclipse now

Comment: The message says "...because one or more required items could not be found." There will be some detail about what can't be found (not what is being installed, they're different). Maybe if you post a screen shot we can determine more.

Answer (score 1):

Run Eclipse as Administrator, if you're not already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue is due to proxy. Please try to download plugin locally, by link:

dl.google.com/android/ADT-16.0.1.zip

extract zip file. 
In Eclipse go to help-> install new software-> Select add

Select to local, and browse to your downloaded package. If problem still persists, try without proxy.

Comment: I thought so too, so I did that. Unfortunately, no luck.