# Trying to install Android ADT and a few other things in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, adt

And I pretty much feel like I'm getting the runaround. I get this error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I was sure I already had this but it's insisting I don't and I don't know where to find it on the Web. Can anybody help? If it helps, I have Linux Mint.

Comment: Follow this guide: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Android Plugin Error with Eclipse Juno 4.2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988741/installing-android-plugin-error-with-eclipse-juno-4-2-0)

Comment: Rog...I think the problem was that I had to reload a few of the sites in "Available Software Sites." I got what I wanted after I did that. Probably would have looked around more if I wasn't in such a hurry yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a similar error while I was trying to install a plugin on new Eclipse version Juno. When I tried it in older version, Indigo, It worked.

Comment: I believe Indigo is the version I have, too. I know I should probably upgrade but I haven't gotten around to it. How did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

To give a little more detail to the 'reload a few things where it says "Available Software Sites"' This is the additional "things" that I loaded to get it to work:

```
Juno
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
The Eclipse Project Updates
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it...Basically what I did was reload a few things where it says "Available Software Sites" in the Help => Install New Software thing, and then tried installing what I wanted again. So I'm going to go ahead and close out this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As another user wrote this:

```
The Eclipse Project Updates
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2
```

I have downloaded Eclipse juno and kept getting those same errors.

Download the ADT Zip Plugin from here:

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip

Copy and paste that to your browser.

Then go ahead and and go to insall updates and put the Eclipse Project link and update that.

Once you do that point to the zip file that you downloaded and you should now have the ADT plugin installed.