# eclipse classic 4.2.1 - starting with android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm starting to program for android OS
I've: -Windows 7 -Eclipse Classic 4.2 -
Downloaded all these required files - http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html -ADT Plugin

I want install new ADT plugin. At first I tried to download it from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse, I add it, but when I selected it there is only "pending.." and nothing has load..(maybe internet connection? I've selected Native connection in preferences after pending it wrotes: Unable to connect to repository http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvidesException )

That's why I download ADT plugin. So if I select downloaded ADT plugin - content of it load - developer tools and ndk plugin so I select all and click next. It loads and writes this:

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. Software being installed: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found"

requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0 this problem is shown here: http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents But there is solution only for version 3.3 and 3.4 (I've 4.2) anyway but I tried it- I look for updates but nothing were found.

I really don't know where could be problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to Update all the plugins in eclipse by **Help -->Check for updates**  and go through the installation steps . If it doesn't help you then

Select Help > Install New Software...

Click the link for Available Software Sites.

Ensure there is an update site named Juno. If this is not present, click Add... and enter 
     **Juno**  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno 

and the same for

    **The Eclipse Project Updates** http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2.

Now go through the installation steps; Eclipse should download and install the plugin's dependencies.

Actual references i followed are https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641507/1154991 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/11463487/1154991

Comment: As I have a proxy server at my university, I get the following error once I Add the repositories :
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2/content.xml
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2/content.xml
Proxy Authentication Required

How can I resolve this ??

Comment: Make sure you have configured your proxy properly in the Eclipse...If not please do that first and then give it a try.

Comment: The URL you have given is a wrong one. Please update that as http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 check and let me know

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by the java version you have installed on your machine. Since android sdk doesn't support java 1.7 it will block you from downloading the plugins if you have installed 1.7. Please make sure you don't have java 1.7 in Program Files(x86) and Program Files. If so uninstall it restart your computer and install only 1.6. Then in Eclipse point to java 1.6 That should allow you to install android SDK and rest of the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You should be familiar with this page: http://developer.android.com/index.html

Download SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Install SDK and Eclipse Plugin: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

And enjoy your Working.

Comment: PUH-LUS ONE... for the links! +1.

Answer (score 1):

in classic version 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' is missing.

check **Contact all update sites during install to find updates.**

This will install required plugin if you are connected to internet.

Hope this helps.