# Android ADT Installation Error

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, adt

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and installed Eclipse from the **Ubuntu Software Center**. Here's the information of the Eclipse I've downloaded. I have Java SDK 6 and 7, but Eclipse is configured to use the Java SDK 6.

```
Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736
```

I was about to install the ADT plug-in on Eclipse when after hitting the first **Next** button in the installation these error telling me I can't install the ADT unless:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you should search a bit first: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first recommendation is to NOT install Eclipse from any Linux package manager or software repository. Instead, just get it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. The builds that linux distro's install are often modified (mangled, some would say).

The particular error you're getting is because ADT requires part of the Eclipse WST project features, but the update sites you have configured don't include WST. Getting one of the packages directly from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ will solve that, along with knowing exactly what you've got (as opposed to relying on whoever assembled the package for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems and the above answer did not work, in this case try:

- deleting workspace directory
- check running eclipse as root (just for duration of this ADT install)

for more info see posts halfway through this thread:

http://androidforums.com/galaxy-nexus-all-things-root/466275-having-trouble-installing-adt-plugin.html

Comment: The link is good if you wanted to preserve the Eclipse version by Ubuntu. In addition this step may take additional tweaks regarding the "adb" file in the Android SDK.

Comment: My solution was also to run as root (via gksudo).  If the problem is that versions of eclipse provided by distros lack certain files then how does running as root fix this problem? (Not being argumentative as I'm not that experienced with Linux - just curious).