# Unable to perform ADT offline installation

Tags: android, plugins, adt

I am trying to install ADT 16.0.1 in Eclipse SDK 3.7.2 in a Mandriva Linux 2011 VM. I've successfully installed Eclipse, and I've downloaded the ADT plugin archive. I've then tried to point Eclipse's "Install New Software" to the archive, which it detects properly. However, when I select all and try to install, it hangs there, with the following regular log messages:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
```

After a while, it just aborts with the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ADT has a dependency on org.eclipse.wst.sse.core, which is the Web Standard Toolkit, located at: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/main.php

This is a duplicate of question [ADT requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found) so I would try those solutions first.

Note that if you want to do an offline install, it might just be easiest to download the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, which includes the WST core plugin: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2  Then  install ADT plugin into that.