# Installing ADT and how to add AVD

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

i hav installed Eclipse Classic.

then, i hav manually tried installing the ADT (addind the .zip from archives) bt in vain.
i also followed this in the eclipse window HELP>INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE and added this url "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" . it showed the development tools containing 4 items. i checked it n clicked NEXT. but it shows the following error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853)

second, i hv installed android SDK17.0 (SDK tools and SDK platform tools) but somewher it showed " failed " while validating the repository.xml file 
it says tht the xml file contains an invalid reg expression [a-zA-Z0-9_-]. how should it b correctd?

third, d AVD manager shows empty list of Andorid Virtual Devices. how to add a valid AVD?

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting programming Android then I advice you to use motodev studio. It is much simpler than eclipse but is based on it and provides an additional functionality

Answer (score 0):

I recently had problems installing Eclipse and Motodev, and Android SDK on WIndows 7, 32 bit. I found a posting somewhere that suggested modifying the control panel setting for "User Account Control Settings", i set this to "Never Notify" and was able to get everything installed. There may be other more secure ways of gettign it to run, but this was what worked for me so I went with it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem (new eclipse install 3 days ago on ubuntu 11.10 32 bit) -The root cause is missing eclipse.wst.sse.core

I enabled (was disabled by default) my version (Eclipse Indigo, version 3.7) of the available software sites (in Help-> Install New software -> available software sites).  Then filtered for 'wst'.   Then selected and installed all the wst software in the tree. Restarted eclipse and the ADT would then install.

See this site for more help on this exact issue.
[ADT requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found)