# Unable to install Android ADT on ubintu12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04

Hi I am unable to install Android ADT and getting following error on ubuntu 12.04.
I am using Eclipse and installing Android ADT by specifing its url https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/   in HELP -> INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE   tab

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447)   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   20.0.2.v201207191942-407447) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Any solution?

Comment: did you try http instead of https?

Comment: What's your eclipse version ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall all of the android components of eclipse .

then , try to install the ADT when running eclipse using

```
sudo ./eclipse
```

if that doesn't work , download the ADT plugin manually and install it :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html (in the "troubleshooting" paragraph).