# eclipse - starting with android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

I want start programming for android.. 
**What I have:**
-Windows 7
-Eclipse Classic 4.2
-Downloaded all there required files - http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
-ADT Plugin

I want install new ADT plugin.. at first I tried to download it from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse, I add it, but if i selected it there is only "pending.." and nothing has load..(maybe internet connection?I have selected Native connection in preferences
after pending it wrotes:
Unable to connect to repository http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvidesException
)

Thats why I download ADT plugin.
So if I select downloaded ADT plugin - content of it load - developer tools and ndk plugin so I select all and click next.
It loads and writes this:

> "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found"
>
> requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0 this problem is shown here:
>   http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html#installeclipsecomponents
>   but there is solution only for version 3.3 and 3.4 (I have 4.2) anyway
>   but I tried it- I look for updates but nothing were found

I really dont know where could be problem..
Thanks for any answer.
(sorry for my english)

I will send 1€ to somebody who can solve my problem ;) (I think all problems all for internet connection but I cant set it..)

Comment: if you follow exactly the official tutorials, you should not have problems. Probably your assumptions are correct, so just wait and try the next day, when hopefully the resources will be available again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this
[ADT requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found)

Comment: finnally I must uninstall eclipse classic and install eclipse for java..and now it works

Answer (score 0):

As described in solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641507/304270) u need to add repository address for **updating Eclipse** as well because ADT plugin requires some of Eclipse components which might not exist in  version u downloaded :)

Links for updating Juno Eclipse is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Be sure that **"Contact all update sites during install.."** option is checked..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
1) Run eclipse as administrator
2) Make sure you have the following urls included as "Available Software Sites"
  (a) for Eclipse juno, "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/"
  (b) "http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2" 
  (c) "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

Hope this helps.

Comment: where to include those urls?