# android development tool error in eclipse kepler and windows 8.1

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried to install adt 23.3.0 in Eclipse Kepler, but I have a problem. I tried every thing such as **run as administrator** or uncheck **contact all update sites ...** But I still have the same problem. I use *Windows 8.1* and the error is:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 

(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 

(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found)

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly positive about this but since this question has received very little attention I figured any answer is better than no answer.

From what my understanding it is done differently in Eclipse Juno which you do from within Eclipse.

Instead you have to download the Android SDK separately and then set the SDK path in preferences...

> window>preferences>Android>sdk location.

Make sure to create a folder in the same directory as Eclipse so Eclipse can easily locate the sdk. Hopefully this helps